# issues using display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm somewhat experienced in html/css coding, but more in the "old school" sense.

My question:  When I use display: inline-block on two divs, they stack on top of each other, despite the fact that they have a defined width and height. and lots of room to float beside.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

(I would attach file to view but it is long, more than willing to zip and send for help)

- Cheers

Comment: do you have any code to show?

Comment: Did you try to add `text-align: center;` on the parent of those 2 `div`s ?

Comment: it sounds to me, that they dont have enough room to float, even though you say they do... what is the padding/margin and width of the two divs? and do they have any borders? and what is the width of the parent div?

Comment: Doesn't it help to put float:left; on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this simple example may be help you to resolve your problem.

Here is a sample `div`, add this to your code base and see the output

```
<style type="text/css">
        .te {
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid #0000FF 1px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>

<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="te">
        hello
    </div>

    <div class="te">
        hello there
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzmDL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just float them left.

css:

```
.block1 {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
}

.block2 {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        background-color: green;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="block1"></div>
<div class="block2"></div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YYSca/2)

Comment: I found the issue, and resolved it. Thanks for all the comments, helped me realize where the error was.